# Overriding __contains__ method for a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

I need to simulate enums in Python, and did it by writing classes like:

```
class Spam(Enum):
    k = 3
    EGGS = 0
    HAM = 1
    BAKEDBEANS = 2
```

Now I'd like to test if some constant is a valid choice for a particular Enum-derived class, with the following syntax:

```
if (x in Foo):
    print("seems legit")
```

Therefore I tried to create an "Enum" base class where I override the `__contains__` method like this:

```
class Enum:
    """
    Simulates an enum.
    """

    k = 0 # overwrite in subclass with number of constants

    @classmethod
    def __contains__(cls, x):
        """
        Test for valid enum constant x:
            x in Enum
        """
        return (x in range(cls.k))
```

However, when using the `in` keyword on the class (like the example above), I get the error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable
```

Why that? Can I somehow get the syntactic sugar I want?

Comment: I think that a clarifiying comment that the code would work fine for:

    if x in Foo():
        print('seems legit')

Would make both the question and the answer easier to understand.

Because the type(Foo()) is Foo but type(Foo) is the meta class.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Why that?

When you use special syntax like `a in Foo`, the `__contains__` method is looked up on the type of `Foo`. However, your `__contains__` implementation exists on `Foo` itself, not its type. `Foo`'s type is `type`, which doesn't implement this (or iteration), thus the error.

The same situation occurs if you instantiate an object and then, *after* it is created, add a `__contains__` function to the instance variables. That function won't be called:

```
>>> class Empty: pass
... 
>>> x = Empty()
>>> x.__contains__ = lambda: True
>>> 1 in x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'Empty' is not iterable
```

> Can I somehow get the syntactic sugar I want?

Yes. As mentioned above, the method is looked up on `Foo`'s type. The type of a class is called a **[metaclass](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation)**, so you need a new metaclass that implements `__contains__`.

Try this one:

```
class MetaEnum(type):
    def __contains__(cls, x):
            return x in range(cls.k)
```

As you can see, the methods on a metaclass take the metaclass instance -- the class -- as their first argument. This should make sense. It's very similar to a classmethod, except that the method lives on the metaclass and not the class.

Inheritance from a class with a custom metaclass also inherits the metaclass, so you can create a base class like so:

```
class BaseEnum(metaclass=MetaEnum):
    pass

class MyEnum(BaseEnum):
    k = 3

print(1 in MyEnum) # True
```

Comment: Ah, I had a vague idea that metaclasses exist, but I never had a use case of my own. This works fine, thanks.

Comment: 8 years later, and this wonderful answer put me on the right track for an issue with I had when switching some packages to Python 3.8. I [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65225753/758174) what I ended up with, in case it is useful for someone else landing here with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

My usecase was to test on the names of the members of my `Enum`.

With a slight modification to this solution:

```
from enum import Enum, EnumMeta, auto


class MetaEnum(EnumMeta):
    def __contains__(cls, item):
        return item in cls.__members__.keys()


class BaseEnum(Enum, metaclass=MetaEnum):
    pass


class LogSections(BaseEnum):
    configuration = auto()
    debug = auto()
    errors = auto()
    component_states = auto()
    alarm = auto()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('configuration' in LogSections)
    print('b' in LogSections)
```

```
True
False
```