# isinstance not working as expected with string enum

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why `isinstance` doesn't seem to be working for me. Is it because I'm using strings or could the post data format be wrong (I print it to the output and it looks right)

```
class Dogs(enum.Enum):
    poodle= 'poodle'
    terrier= 'terrier'

@blueprint.route('/test/<int:test_id>', methods=['post'])
def test(int:test_id):
    data = request.json
    print(data) #it's poodle
    if isinstance(data, Dog):        
        return HTTPStatus.OK

return HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST
```

Comment: It's because you're using strings. The type of `data` is `str`, not `Dog`. You'd want to instead use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63335753/how-to-check-if-string-exists-in-enum-of-strings) to check whether the enum _contains_ the value you want.

Comment: Side-note: Your enum class is named `Dogs`, your test is against `Dog`. Typo in copying? Or mistake in actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable data is a string object - it isn't an object instance of class Dogs, which is why isinstance will return false regardless of what's in the data variable. Something like this should work instead of isinstance:

```
# if isinstance(data, Dog):    
if data in Dogs.__members__:
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a try-catch block.

```
   try:
     Dogs(data)
   except ValueError:
     return HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST
 return HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST
```

I think this is a terrible answer, but it works.